# Errors on update after trying to install Python 2.7?

Tags: python, 17.04

After trying to install Python 2.7 in my Ubuntu 17.04:

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
```

I started getting error whenever I am running the update:

```
$ sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get update           
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease [89.2 kB]
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                 
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty Release                                                   
Hit:4 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                 
Hit:5 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Hit:12 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x zesty InRelease
Fetched 89.2 kB in 0s (129 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any ideas why? How can fix this?

These are the errors I guess:

```
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes` PPA ([Launchpad link](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes)) only supports Ubuntu releases up to 16.04 (Xenial). It simply does not offer any packages for 17.04 (Zesty).

You have to remove the repository again, it is not compatible with your Ubuntu release.

If you added the repository with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes`, you can remove it again easily with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
```

---

However, 17.04 already has Python 2.7 preinstalled: http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/python

Anyway, messing with the system's Python version is dangerous as it can easily break lots of important applications if you accidentally remove one of the preinstalled Python versions or replace them with an incompatible one. Just leave it as it is.

Comment: thanks. `You have to remove the repository again, it is not compatible with your Ubuntu release.`  how do i remove it?

Comment: @teelou You can use `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes`. I edited my answer to include that. If this solves your question, please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the grey check mark on its left. Otherwise feel free to ask back if something is still unclear.